# To let the animation complete on mouse leave

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations, keyframe

I have written keyframe animation on hover.

```
@keyframes juggle {
    0%{ transform: skew(15deg, 15deg) translate(0,10px);}
    50%{ transform: skew(-15deg, -15deg) translate(0,-10px);}
    100%{ transform: skew(15deg, 15deg) translate(0,0);}
}
span:hover{ animation: juggle 1s; }
```

The animation works fine but on mouse leave, it stops abruptly.
The expectation is to complete the animation even on mouse leave.

Is it possible to do it without jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works

```
let section = document.getElementById('homeSection');
let elmnt = section.getElementsByClassName('classname');

for (let i = 0; i < elmnt.length; i++) {
    elmnt[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
        elmnt[i].classList.add('Juggle');
        setTimeout(function(){
            elmnt[i].classList.remove('Juggle')
        },400)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is something you trying to do

```
span {
  animation-name: juggle-out;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-repeat-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
span:hover{
  animation-name: juggle-in;
}
@keyframes juggle-in {
    0%{ transform: skew(15deg, 15deg) translate(0,10px);}
    50%{ transform: skew(-15deg, -15deg) translate(0,-10px);}
    100%{ transform: skew(15deg, 15deg) translate(0,0);}
}

@keyframes juggle-out {
    0%{ transform: skew(15deg, 15deg) translate(0,10px);}
    50%{ transform: skew(-15deg, -15deg) translate(0,-10px);}
    100%{ transform: skew(0deg, 0deg) translate(0,0);}
}
```

you should use 2 animations for `hover in` and `hover out`
actually there is no `hover in` and `hover out` in CSS
It's just a state but the `animation-fill-mode` plays an important role
The support is not very good though ;)
I recommend adding class instead of this

Comment: By your code another animation will be triggered when mouse leaves. But what i expect is for the animation which started during the hover should be completed ( should not end without completing ). I don't want my animation to end incomplete. I think i made my point clear here.

Comment: use adding/removing classes with setTimeout for removing, and stop re-triggering the same event,

Comment: the animation is done only once on hover. when mouse leaves the animation stops automatically before completing the animation. even without removing the animation it stops. **I want my animation to continue till it ends**

Comment: It can be done with a trick purely CSS, hmmm, is the item in the menu?

Comment: No it's just a text with letters in a seperate span tag. Can you explain it, or direct me to some reference where i could learn it.

Comment: If possible i want it to be solved by css. If not, with js

Comment: I did love to, but only if you send. My site is under under construction, so please do it as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onmouseover function to add a class which contains the animation and manually remove the class using settimeout function.